# Can we build username/password for GCP while creating VM

Tags: java, linux, google-cloud-platform, cloud, virtual-machine

I am trying to create VM on Google cloud compute though java code.
VM's are getting created on GCP but I don't know how to access them.

How we can create username and password while creating VM? Is there any builder or way to add username and password. ?

Thanks in advance !!

Below is my code:

````
private void createVMInstance(String projectId, String sourceImage, String zone, String diskType, String vmName, String vmSize)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException, ExecutionException, TimeoutException {
        String machineType = String.format("zones/%s/machineTypes/n1-standard-1", zone);
        long diskSizeGb = Long.parseLong(vmSize);
        String networkName = "default";
        InstancesSettings instancesSettings = InstancesSettings.newBuilder()
                .setCredentialsProvider(FixedCredentialsProvider.create(googleCredential)).build();
        try (InstancesClient instancesClient = InstancesClient.create(instancesSettings)) {
            // Instance creation requires at least one persistent disk and one network interface.
            AttachedDisk disk = AttachedDisk.newBuilder().setBoot(true).setAutoDelete(true).setType(AttachedDisk.Type.PERSISTENT.toString())
                    .setDeviceName("disk-1").setInitializeParams(AttachedDiskInitializeParams.newBuilder()
                            .setSourceImage(sourceImage).setDiskSizeGb(diskSizeGb).setDiskType(diskType).build()).build();
            NetworkInterface networkInterface = NetworkInterface.newBuilder()
                    .setName(networkName).build();
            // Bind `instanceName`, `machineType`, `disk`, and `networkInterface` to an instance.
            Instance instanceResource = Instance.newBuilder().setName(vmName).setMachineType(machineType)
                    .addDisks(disk).addNetworkInterfaces(networkInterface).build();
            // Insert the instance in the specified project and zone.
            InsertInstanceRequest insertInstanceRequest = InsertInstanceRequest.newBuilder().setProject(projectId)
                    .setZone(zone).setInstanceResource(instanceResource).build();
            OperationFuture<Operation, Operation> operation = instancesClient.insertAsync(
                    insertInstanceRequest);
            // Wait for the operation to complete.
            Operation response = operation.get(3, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
            if (response.hasError()) {
                throw new GCPConnectorException("GCP VM : Failed to create VM in GCP." + response);
            }
        }
    }```
````

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

> *VM's are getting created on GCP but I don't know how to access them.*

There are many ways you might want to access.

If accessing from some other internal GCP resource (like another VM), you can use the private internal IP address.

If accessing from outside GCP altogether, such as ssh'ing from your computer to the VM, then you will need to configure a few things to make that work – create a GCP firewall, assign it a tag, add that tag to your VM. From there, you would be able to ssh to that VM instance like this (replace "us-central1-a" with whatever zone):

```
gcloud compute ssh \
--zone "us-central1-a" \
--project "project-name-here" \
"vm-instance-name-goes-here"
```